# Running the npm ls react-dom shows duplicates

Tags: reactjs

I ran the `npm ls react-dom` command and I'm getting the following output

```
│ ├── react-dom@17.0.0 deduped invalid: "~0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from node_modules/jodit-react, "^16.9.0" from node_modules/react-datepicker, "0.14.x || 15.x.x || 16.x.x" from node_modules/react-daterange-picker, "^16.0.0" from node_modules/react-google-login, "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from node_modules/react-lazyload, "^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^ 16.0.0" from node_modules/react-meta-tags, "^0.14.6 || 15.x.x || 16.x.x" from node_modules/react-paypal-button-v2, "^16.8.0" from node_modules/react-select, "^16.7.0" from node_modules/react-social-sharing
│ ├─┬ styled-components@4.4.1
│ │ └── react-dom@17.0.0 deduped invalid: "~0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from node_modules/jodit-react, "^16.9.0" from node_modules/react-datepicker, "0.14.x || 15.x.x || 16.x.x" from node_modules/react-daterange-picker, "^16.0.0" from node_modules/react-google-login, "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from node_modules/react-lazyload, "^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^ 16.0.0" from node_modules/react-meta-tags, "^0.14.6 || 15.x.x || 16.x.x" from node_modules/react-paypal-button-v2, "^16.8.0" from node_modules/react-select, "^16.7.0" from node_modules/react-social-sharing, "^15.5.4 || ^16.0.0-0" from node_modules/react-stripe-elements, "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from node_modules/react-with-firebase-auth
│ └─┬ styled-is@1.3.0
│   └── react-dom@17.0.0 deduped invalid: "~0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from node_modules/jodit-react, "^16.9.0" from node_modules/react-datepicker, "0.14.x || 15.x.x || 16.x.x" from node_modules/react-daterange-picker, "^16.0.0" from node_modules/react-google-login, "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from node_modules/react-lazyload, "^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^ 16.0.0" from node_modules/react-meta-tags, "^0.14.6 || 15.x.x || 16.x.x" from node_modules/react-paypal-button-v2, "^16.8.0" from node_modules/react-select, "^16.7.0" from node_modules/react-social-sharing, "^15.5.4 || ^16.0.0-0" from node_modules/react-stripe-elements, "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from node_modules/react-with-firebase-auth, "^16.8.4" from node_modules/react-social-sharing/node_modules/styled-is
├─┬ react-stripe-elements@5.0.1
│ └── react-dom@17.0.0 deduped invalid: "~0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from node_modules/jodit-react, "^16.9.0" from node_modules/react-datepicker, "0.14.x || 15.x.x || 16.x.x" from node_modules/react-daterange-picker, "^16.0.0" from node_modules/react-google-login, "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from node_modules/react-lazyload, "^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^ 16.0.0" from node_modules/react-meta-tags, "^0.14.6 || 15.x.x || 16.x.x" from node_modules/react-paypal-button-v2, "^16.8.0" from node_modules/react-select, "^16.7.0" from node_modules/react-social-sharing, "^15.5.4 || ^16.0.0-0" from node_modules/react-stripe-elements
├─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.1
│ └── react-dom@17.0.0 deduped invalid: "~0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from node_modules/jodit-react, "^16.9.0" from node_modules/react-datepicker, "0.14.x || 15.x.x || 16.x.x" from node_modules/react-daterange-picker, "^16.0.0" from node_modules/react-google-login, "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from node_modules/react-lazyload, "^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^ 16.0.0" from node_modules/react-meta-tags, "^0.14.6 || 15.x.x || 16.x.x" from node_modules/react-paypal-button-v2, "^16.8.0" from node_modules/react-select, "^16.7.0" from node_modules/react-social-sharing, "^15.5.4 || ^16.0.0-0" from node_modules/react-stripe-elements
└─┬ react-with-firebase-auth@1.0.5
  └── react-dom@17.0.0 deduped invalid: "~0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from node_modules/jodit-react, "^16.9.0" from node_modules/react-datepicker, "0.14.x || 15.x.x || 16.x.x" from node_modules/react-daterange-picker, "^16.0.0" from node_modules/react-google-login, "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from node_modules/react-lazyload, "^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^ 16.0.0" from node_modules/react-meta-tags, "^0.14.6 || 15.x.x || 16.x.x" from node_modules/react-paypal-button-v2, "^16.8.0" from node_modules/react-select, "^16.7.0" from node_modules/react-social-sharing, "^15.5.4 || ^16.0.0-0" from node_modules/react-stripe-elements, "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from node_modules/react-with-firebase-auth
```

Seems like there are duplicates. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and read this article:

https://blog.elantha.com/more-than-one-copy-of-react-in-the-same-app/

In my case, I had an app created with "Create React App" so the second solution fixed it for me using the method explained here. I had to rewire react.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired

Steps:

1- in the command line of the project write

```
npm install react-app-rewired --save-dev
```

2 - Create a file named config-overrides.js in the root directory, where README is.

3- Write the following code inside the file:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = { 
  webpack(config) {
    config.resolve.alias['react']
      = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react');
      
    return config;
  }
};
```

4- Open the package.json and find the "scripts" . 'Flip' the existing calls to react-scripts in npm scripts for start, build and test and you should get a code looking like this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

5- Now after you start the server with command "npm start" your site should work